# Convert multiple excel sheets into PDF with file name as sheet name and help in formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have around 900 sheets in a workbook and i am trying to convert selected columns from each sheet to a pdf file so i will have around 900 pdfs. The issue arising is that number of rows in each sheet varies and can be around 3000 and i want to have it in maximum 10 PDF sheets. Currently the code that i use generates 1 PDF file with 100 pages for 3000 rows.

I am looking for a good formatting option so that pages in PDF are reduced.

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastDataRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Control As Worksheet
    Dim strPath As String, fileName As String
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer


    With ThisWorkbook
        Set Control = .Sheets("Control")
        strPath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("C4")
        If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath & "\"
        fileName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("C5")
    End With
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(strPath & fileName)
    
    wbTarget.Activate
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws
            lastDataRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        End With
        Cells.Select
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

        Set rng = ws.Range("B1:C" & lastDataRow)
        rng.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        rng.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, strPath & ws.Name & ".pdf"
    Next ws

    MsgBox "Conversion Complete.", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try `ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 10`? This would zoom the pages so you have 10 pages in height maximum. Note that the text can get really small if you push 3000 rows into 10 pages it is probably not readable anymore. • Your question is very broad and unclear, because you didn't ask one. You need to ask something that we can answer if you want a clear answer. • You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: Note that if you use the worksheets name `ws.Name` for your file name without filtering not allowed characters, this might easily error. Eg if your sheet name contains `<` or `>` you cannot use them in a file name and your code breaks. Make sure to filter out not allowed characters for file names.

Comment: Initially my sheet has data in 2 columns A and B. I would like to split it into 4 parts so it will occupy columns A-H, reduce row height to 10 and text to 6 and then save the file as PDF. Eg if i have Emp Id and name in 2 columns 3000 rows. I would like to split it into 8 columns A-H i.e 4 pairs.

Comment: Well, what have you tried to exactly do that (split A and B into multiple columns)? We cannot write that code for you, you need to come up with some attempt and a question to it. Macro recorder might help too.